# How to match c++ with word boundaries

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I want to match the word "c++" with word boundaries in Python 3. But my guess is that the \b also triggers on the plus sign.

I've simplified down to the following test case for clarity:

```
\bc\+\+\b
```

I'm hoping that I can keep the word boundaries but change its settings somehow.

The reason for this is that I want to put the regex in a token_pattern in a TfidfVectorizer in which I don't have control over how they use it.

[Link to online regex tool](https://pythex.org)

Comment: Try `(?<!\S)c\+\+(?!\S)` or keep first word boundary. It actually depends on what you expect from a word boundary.

Comment: how about this case `some text -c++... with .c+++` ?

Comment: As usual use `(?<!\w)c\+\+(?!\w)`

Answer (score 1):

There are very limited ways how you can influence the "behaviour" of character classes - they are called flags:

[re.ASCII](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.ASCII) ... [re.VERBOSE](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.VERBOSE)

They f.e. allow `r'.'` to match newlines (`re.DOTALL`), change the behavior of `^$` (`re.MULTILINE`) or make your regex match without case-awareness (`re.IGNORECASE`).

None of them changes `\b` to not having `'+'` in it. If you want to match `c++` with wordboundaries you have to mimic the `\b`-behaviour in your pattern:

> ```
> \b    Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word. 
>       A word is defined as a sequence of word characters. Note that formally, 
>       \b is defined as the boundary between a \w and a \W character (or vice versa), 
>       or between \w and the beginning/end of the string. This means that r'\bfoo\b' 
>       matches 'foo', 'foo.', '(foo)', 'bar foo baz' but not 'foobar' or 'foo3'.
> ```

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Easiest would probably to mach 'c++' with a word boundary before and a whitespace or non-word character after it. `r'\bc\+\+[\s\W]'` but this would also match `'c+++'`. If you want to match exclusively `'c++'` but not `'c+++'` you might want to put a `'\s'` into your pattern and extend it with other characters you allow:

```
r'\b(c\+\+)[\s.,!?]'
```

Extend characters in bracked to accomodate more things allowed after a c++ - excluding them from the grouping (c++) will need them to match but not include them into the group.

As for regex-test tools, maybe change to https://regex101.com/ - it has python support and you can even *save* patterns and test-text and provide a link:

https://regex101.com/r/6XtVTS/1